# Directory Not Found Exception or FileNotFoundException on VLC.DotNet

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, vlc

Using the VLC library provided by Vlc.DotNet, I have tried to implement it in a simple WPF.

I copied exactly the code from the repository, and got the NuGet online, but can't seem to make it work. I get a Directory Not Found exception straight from the load of the file on the disk.

Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        VLCControl.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory;
    }


    private void OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
        if (currentDirectory == null)
            return;
        if (AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(currentAssembly.Location).ProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitecture.X86)
            e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\..\lib\x86\"));
        else
            e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\..\lib\x64\"));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        d.Multiselect = false;
        if (d.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Uri src = new Uri(d.FileName);
            VLCControl.MediaPlayer.Play(src); //Exception here
        }
    }
```

VLCControl being the VLC control in the xaml.

By changing the `VlcLibDirectory` with another path where I put the libraries (for example the root of application), I get this StackTrace :

> at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcInteropsManager..ctor(DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath)
>    at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager..ctor(DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath)
>    at Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.VlcManager.GetInstance(DirectoryInfo dynamicLinkLibrariesPath)
>    at Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer..ctor(DirectoryInfo vlcLibDirectory)
>    at Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl.EndInit()
>    at Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl.Play(Uri uri, String[] options)
>    at VLCTest.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\VLCTest\VLCTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:ligne 56

The code becomes :

```
 if(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(currentAssembly.Location).ProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitecture.X86)
     e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);
 else
     e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you start this from VS? Going from the currentDirectory is there a folder x86 or x64 ("..\..\..\lib\x86\")

Comment: @Default It sure does, since it is a path from the file you get from the FileDialog.  @Jehof, the Exception occurs when the file loads, not the player itself. The player actually gets the good path for the `VlcLibDirectory` (I think?), thanks to the library

Comment: @Jehof Sorry for the double comment. Yes in VS.

Comment: I do not mean the path to the file selected by the FileDialog. The path that is assigned to `VlcLibDirectory` does it exists? Have you checked that in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Jehof As far as I know it does. If I change `VlcLibDirectory` to another path and put the dll into it, the Exception changes and it become `FileNotFoundException`, even when the **Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll** is inside.

Comment: How about checking it instead of 'afaik it should' non-debugging? `libPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\..\lib\x86\"); if (!Directory.Exists(libPath)) throw new Exception("Path actually did not exist");`

Comment: How about I already did. "As far as I know" is just an expression. I wouldn't have just assumed. And I proved it by testing another method. Thanks

Comment: @Default Ow, ok sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Since we are talking about missing files here, can you provide a local directory tree of the project related files and mark the different areas? (The assembly location, the library location, the location of the file you chose when using the OpenFileDialog?

Comment: @grek40 I have created a repo, you can check it [here](https://github.com/JoJoeTheBear/VLCTest), and another thing you could possibly do is check the [Vlc.DotNet repository](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) as well. For the OpenFile Dialog, I don't see how it could help since the file can be anywhere, and the path is actually perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is definitely with your library path, though you have to debug the problem yourself in order to find the exact discrepancy between provided path and actual path.

The misunderstanding may be, which libraries are missing. You do have the `Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll` but your are missing the nativ libraries behind. This is the reason, why the exception occurs **inside** `Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll` when it tries to load the actual libraries.

The `OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory` function is called inside `VLCControl.MediaPlayer.Play(src);`, so the Path from OpenFileDialog has nothing to do with the problem.

Steps I taken to reproduce / fix:

- Downloaded your project
- Tested / Debugged

  - Exception occurred as you describe
- Downloaded the libraries from Vlc.DotNet repository
- Changed the paths to absolute values
- Tested / Debugged again

  - Successfully played a music file
  - Another exception occured on closing (different story alltogether)

My folder layout:

Solution path:

> D:\Programmierung\VLCTest-VAlphaTesting\VLCTest-VAlphaTesting\

Actual Assembly location on execute

> D:\Programmierung\VLCTest-VAlphaTesting\VLCTest-VAlphaTesting\VLCTest\bin\Debug

ProcessorArchitecture: x86

Library Path:

> D:\Programmierung\Vlc.DotNet-master\Vlc.DotNet-master\lib\x86

Contents of library path:

> plugins (folder)
>
> .keep (file)
>
> libvlc.dll (file)
>
> libvlccore.dll (file)

For testing purposes I hardcoded the library path - you may want to do that as well

```
if (AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(currentAssembly.Location).ProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitecture.X86)
    e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Programmierung\Vlc.DotNet-master\Vlc.DotNet-master\lib\x86");
else
    e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Programmierung\Vlc.DotNet-master\Vlc.DotNet-master\lib\x64");
```

Comment: That is a very cool answer. May I ask : How did you find the native lib bug? I tried to execute the native project but it did not work and could'nt even debug. I will test the solution as soon as I get home and accept the answer. Cheers.

Comment: The answer might be a bit unsatisfactory, but it was more or less intuition. I did not bother with anything like the native project. Consider the following thoughts: (1) nuget does it right by itself - means, there is no need to take care of anything within the Vlc.DotNet.* libraries. (2) Interop is a typical name for a mediator between DotNet stuff and external native interfaces. (3) distinguishing between x86 and x64 also indicates the involvement of native libraries. (4) setting the right path after being sure of the problem was a one-shot, so I didn't think to much here

Comment: Well, I think I wouldn't have found by myself. I have now a problem to try compiling in 64 bits, but one issue at a time. 
Thank you for your help.